# nginx if condition with cookie/header value 0

Tags: nginx

I have a cookie and a header named type and having value 0, 1, 2 (Main issue is with 0). I am trying to set a variable based on the value from cookie and header, with more preference to header value

I have a following condition in nginx

```
if ($cookie_type) {
  set $exp_type "exp$cookie_type";
}

if ($http_type) {
  set $exp_type "exp$http_type";
}
```

So the type is first fetched from cookie and if there is a value (allowed values 0, 1, 2 ) set in the variable exp_type and value looks like exp0, exp1, exp2. And if there is header, its given more preference

This works perfectly fine for values 1 and 2 but not 0 and I figured out why. The reason is because the since the value translates to 0 and if(0) is treated as false.

So I wanted to check if there is any workaround or completely different way to do this as I also read in many posts that if should not be used in nginx

Comment: Try: `if ($cookie_type ~ ^[0-2]$) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to use `map` for these kinds of purposes. Define the maps on `http` level:

```
map $http_type $exp_type {
    2 exp2;
    1 exp1;
    0 exp0;
    default $exp_cookie;
}

map $cookie_type $exp_cookie {
    2 exp2;
    1 exp1;
    0 exp0;
    default "";
}
```

When there is a reference to `$ext_type` variable, nginx will look up the result using the first map, checking `http_type` value against the map.

If no matching entry is found in first map, the `default` value points to `$exp_cookie`, which is resolved using the second map.

You can amend the map matching with regular expressions and capture groups, and use capture results in the mapped values.

Comment: Thank you!!! Thats exactly what I did and worked